# Products showing out of stock even though they are in stock

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a Configurable Product and used the simple import tool (System->Import/Export) to import the Simple Products that will be associated with the Configurable Product.  I am able to associate the Simple Products to the Configurable Product without any issues, however when I look at the front-end it shows out of stock.  I have been troubleshooting this for days now and found an odd occurrence.  If I go into a Simple Product, switch 'Choose Store View' from Default to the actual store I want it to show up on, and click Save (no other modifications made) the product is available for attribute selection containing the 1 Simple Product that I saved.  I have re-imported the Simple Products several times (including putting the store name in the '_store' variable) however nothing has worked.

Does anyone know what may be being set in the DB when saving a Simple Product with a 'Choose Store View' option selected?  I have a lot of products that I need to import and have everything mapped beautifully, I just can not set this 1 variable.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you including in your import csv a "is_in_stock" column, with a "1" supplied for each product?

Comment: Yes I am setting that flag to 1.

Comment: "If I go into a Simple Product, switch 'Choose Store View' from Default to the actual store I want it to show up on, and click Save (no other modifications made)" <-- A similar scenario has happened to me in the past. If I remember correctly, it did not have to do with whether or not the product was in stock, but instead the product didn't seem to be fully setup correctly from the import. I believe not all necessary product data was included in the original import. Saving the product through the Magento admin web interface for "edit product" would fill in the missing data.

Comment: Does saving the product on the default store view correct the problem as well (without any changes)? or is it only when you switch to front end store's view?

Comment: If I save the product with default nothing happens however if I select the store view, and not,change anything, it will save correct and show up on the front end.  Do you happen to remember what variable you added to the import to correct this?  I dove into the database and can not find what field is different between an imported product and one that is added manually.  I agree with you though I am convinced it is not a stock issue it has something to do with an association field not being set.

Comment: I have also confirmed the export fields are identical as well when running the standard Product export.

Comment: sorry I do not remember what was mis-configured when I came across this similar situation. I never use the built in System -> Import/Export, but instead write shell scripts in the "/shell" folder, utilizing the Mage_Shell_Abstract class. Parse out CSV files, and create the products myself using the Mage classes.

Comment: you've stated that you have the data mapped out very well already... if you have shell access and the programming know how, I'd recommend trying to import products this way. I'd be happy to answer questions where I can.

Comment: Thank-you for the information.  Unfortunately I do not have the programming know how for something like this.  Do you happen to have a template you have used in the past that I may be able to start with?

Comment: I can read code fairly well and understand what it is doing and how, however starting from scratch I would not know how to begin.

Comment: If you can email me at least a portion of your data set (maybe like the first 10-20 products, doesn't need to be the whole thing, make sure to include at least one configurable product and all of that configurable's simple products) I can do my best to explain how start creating your import script. I'll add my email address in a comment after this one (plan to remove after you get it)

Comment: Thanks Meogi, however I was able to sort it out.  I ended up uploading the products through Import/Export - Data Profiles - Import and the products can be associated correctly.  Thanks for your assistance and willingness to help.

Comment: Sounds good Tom. I'd recommend posting your solution in here as an answer so that the community can use that information should someone else come into a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by using the Dataflow Profiles import routines (System-Import/Export-Dataflow Profiles) rather than just the standard Import/Export functionality.  There are a few additional fields provided using the 'Import All Products' than with the standard import that must have made the difference.  The exact process I followed is below.

1. Go to 'System-Import/Export-Dataflow Profiles' and select 'Export All Products'.  Select 'Run Profile' and it will generate a .csv file in the var/export folder
2. Get the file (FTP is easiest) and use the same fields that were provided in the export to build your list of products to import.  I simply used the same fields that were exported for the products I added manually to ensure they were the same and update the product specific items (i.e. SKU, description, price, etc)
3. Once the new products are in the file, go to 'System-Import/Export-Dataflow Profiles' and select 'Import All Products'.  Select 'Upload File' and find the file that was created in step 2.  Once you have found the file and uploaded it select 'Save Profile'.
4. The final step is to go to 'Run Profile', select the file that you have just uploaded, and click 'Run Profile in Popup'.  You will see how many records will be imported as well as a status bar for the progress.  After the import is complete it will automatically re-index the necessary tables and the products are available in the store/category designated.

Comment: feel free to accept this answer if this works for you